# How to forward all my emails from my old gmail account to new gmail account using google script

Tags: google-apps-script

I got new gmail id. So I want to forward all my emails including attachments from old mail to new mail using google scripts.

If there are any free tools to forward all emails, please suggest that also.

Comment: This is a built-in functionality in Google. Go to settings -> TAB Forwarding and POP/IMAP.

Answer (score 1):

While it is possible to write a Google Script that forwards emails to another email, it will likely not work in your case since GmailApp service only allows 100 emails per day (1500, if you have GSuite).

Gmail has a built-in tool for importing emails from another account via the POP protocol. It would, however, require you to generate an app-specific password in your Google Accounts dashboard since the POP3 protocol needs the password in plain text.

See: [How to Copy Emails in Gmail](https://www.labnol.org/internet/copy-gmail-messages/28085/)

Comment: It is showing "The setting you are looking for is not available for your account." when I'm accessing app-passwords page.